# Nifi is not working. When I run the windows batch file to run Nifi it closes on it's own

Tags: apache-nifi

I downloaded Nifi version 1.15.3. I ran the windows batch file to run nifi. The command line opens and certain instructions run but it closes on it's own. I downloaded the latest version of Nifi, it worked but there was no option for ECMA script.

[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz42d.png)

[web pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKBJq.png)

My log file looks like this-

```
2022-06-03 10:15:23,354 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @664f1c53
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.injectSnappyNativeLoader(SnappyLoader.java:297)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:227)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.<clinit>(PutHiveStreaming.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.getClass(StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.java:330)
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.documentConfigurableComponent(DocGenerator.java:100)
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:65)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1139)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:170)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:82)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:330)
```

Comment: Run `cmd`, run the batch file from there, edit your post and add the output.

Comment: Hey I added the output

Comment: Hm, it seems that it started up fine and crashed later. You'll probably have to look at a log file to see why, but I don't know nifi or windows well enough to tell you where. (Also, please don't post screenshots of text, post the actual text in a \`\`\` code block. It keeps things searchable.)

Comment: Seems you are using java version that is incompatible with nifi

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_requirements

Answer (score 0):

I was using Java 18 before, now I changed it into java 11. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue previously I am using java17 java8 it works fine for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33671880)